# I am not able to run docker image on M1 chip

Tags: docker, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am new to Docker and trying to run the sample image using the following commands but it is not working. I can see the logs on the terminal but when I hit http://localhost:5555/ nothing happens.

logs:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -p 5555:5555 in28min/hello-world-python:0.0.1.RELEASE
 * Serving Flask app "launch" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 105-668-588
```

1. docker run -p 5555:5555 in28min/hello-world-python:0.0.1.RELEASE
2. docker run -p 5555:5555 in28min/hello-world-java:0.0.1.RELEASE

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It's running on port 5000 inside the container, so map `5555:5000` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @frippe
Now I am able to run it. After that, I checked a few online tutorials and found this concept of mapping port between host machine and docker.